# Generate file by template using maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, velocity, file-generation

I have a directory that contains several children-directories. These directories are being  generated by maven assembly plugin. I want to generate the .properties file that contains smth like

```
module1.home=${.dir}/module1
module2.home=${.dir}/module2
```

and so on. So I want 1 line for each child-directory. I have a velocity template that describes content of the file.
Which plugin can do it for me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The [velocity-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/velocity-maven-plugin/) do a great job at allowing you to run your Velocity templates during build.